# How to format interval to hours : minutes in pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

When we use **this query**

```
select '2930:41:51.974223'::interval(0);
```

**Output**

```
 interval  
------------
 2930:41:52
```

**Desired Output**

> 2930:42

**I tried**

```
select to_char('2930:41:51.974223'::interval(0),'HH24:MI');
```

**Results:**

```
 to_char 
---------
 2930:41
```

It won't round 41 to 42 by adding the seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add 30 seconds to the interval:

```
select to_char('2930:41:51.974223'::interval(0)+ '30s','HH24:MI');

 to_char 
---------
 2930:42
(1 row)
```

Comment: `+ '30'` yields the same result

Comment: Yeah Thanks klin!. Is there is any built-in functions for this time manipulation?

Comment: There are no functions more convenient for this case than `to_char()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char('2930:41:51.974223' + interval '30','HH24:MI');
```

or

```
select to_char('2930:41:51.974223' + interval  '30 seconds','HH24:MI');
```